# Does a terminating recurrence relation diverge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence relation
$$u_1=-3.25 \ \& \ u_{k+1}=\frac{4}{u_k+2}$$
is $\{u_k\}$ convergent?

A quick check for the definition of convergence gives the following:

If $\forall \epsilon \ \exists L\exists N$ s.t. $\forall n>N$, $|u_n-L|<\epsilon$, then $\{u_k\}$ is convergent. Otherwise, it is divergent.

Since no such $(L,N)$ exists, it is divergent.

However, by listing out the first 6 terms, $\{-3.25,-3.2,-3\frac{1}{3},-3,-4,-2\}$, we realise that $u_k$ is undefined when $k\geq7$.

Does it even make sense to discuss convergence of a terminating recurrence relation?

Comment: As you've noticed, the expression $u_{k+1} = \frac{4}{u_k + 2}$ doesn't make sense when $k = 6$ (so there should really be a caveat in the definition). What is your definition of 'sequence', and does $\{u_k\}$ fit it? If this isn't even a sequence (in this case, because it fails to be infinite), it doesn't make sense to ask whether or not it converges.

Answer (score 1):

If you speak about a recurrence relation being convergent, that is actually just shorthand for speaking about whether *the sequence defined by the recurrence relation* converges or not.

In order to converge, a sequence needs to be *infinite*. It is allowed for its terms to be all identical from a certain point on, but there does needs to be an infinity of terms in the first place.

In this case, your recurrence *does not define an infinite sequence* at all. Therefore, in particular, it doesn't define any *converging* sequence, so it would be be wrong to say that the recurrence "converges".

Comment: Could we not perhaps say such finite sequences converge vacuously? I.e.,  since terms after seven aren't defined, there aren't any terms after the sixth that violate the bounding condition in the definition of convergence.

Comment: @DavidH: we can choose to say whatever we want, of course, but that would not be a _useful_ definition. For example, if we say that, we lose the important theorem that a convergent sequence has exactly one limit -- because _every_ number would qualify (vacuously) for being a limit of every finite sequence.

Comment: Ah, that's a very convincing reason not to do that. :)

Comment: this actually now begs the followup question, does the sequence I define above qualify as a finite sequence? A finite sequence terminates nicely, but the recurrence relation terminates by being undefined.

Comment: @Poseidonium: That would depend on the exact mechanism you use to define the solution of a recurrence; it could either result in saying a finite sequence is the solution, or that there is no solution. In any case, it is clear that there is no _infinite_ sequence that solves it.